# Binding same EndPoint for TcpListener and TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a **listener** that listens to the localhost on an assigned portnumber like this:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localIP);
listener.Start();

while (true) {
listen:
    if (!listener.Pending()) {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        goto listen;
    }
    Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
}
```

Now the same program should make a connection to other instances of this program like this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(localIP); //localendpoint should use same port
client.Connect("localhost", remotePort);
```

As you can see I'm binding the same `IPEndPoint localIP` for both the **listener** and **client**. So that whenever another instance of the program has a connection with this one, the socket in the listener could give me it's `RemoteEndPoint`. So that I don't get a random port number generated by the system. Of course this won't work and I get this error:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted

Since both listener and client are binded to the same `IPEndPoint localIP`.

Is there a workaround so that I can bind a listener and client to the same EndPoint? Because I want to get the portnumber from `socket.RemoteEndPoint` in the listener. This portnumber should be the portnumber that is assigned to each individual instance of the program.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Of course you can't use the same local tcp port for 2 connections, how would the system know which of the two connections should receive a packet when one arrives? That's the whole point of ports. But this should never be needed. I don't understand what the problem is, or why "new TcpClient(localIP)" would help with it.

Comment: Well, like I said, my purpose is to get the port number the program on the other side of the socket is listening to for it's own incoming connections. Instead, the system creates a random portnumber whenever I would just do `TcpClient client = new TcpClient()`.

Comment: I don't understand why the random port is a problem. Are you trying to get the remote port from the *listener* connection? Try reading the remote port of the *accepted* connection - your Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket(); connection, not the listener.

Comment: Suppose I start two instances of this application. Program A would be assigned to listen on port 1000 and program B would be assigned to listen on port 1001. Now program A connects to B. B would indeed accept this and return the socket. On the socket, when I ask for it's RemoteEndPoint, I get the random generated port number. But I want the port number program A listens to, which is 1000.

Comment: I explained why this doesn't make sense. Imagine program A using local port 1000, and program B using local port 1000. A packet arrives to my IP, port 1000. Which connection should receive the data? Your options are to: 1) use raw sockets, Windows 7 doesn't allow those any more so you need a library or something. This is the most powerful but the most complicated solution 2) send the client's listening port as data over the connection 3) make the client's listening port mathematically deducible from its client port - bind the client to listening port + 1 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on the comments from the question, the best solution would be just to send the port number the program is listening to over the socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) for your communications. It gives you a lot of handy tools for abstracting over serialization, the transport protocol, security, configuration, etc. Eventually, WCF lets you build service-oriented apps for a diverse client ecosystem easier than doing all the hard work yourself.

One of the features WCF has to offer is a so-called [Duplex Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx), which should give you what you want: a connecting client immediately announces a way to be called back.

If you still need to communicate your network topology, than you can still do so using WCF; And for that I recommend implementing a separate service interface that takes care of network topology exclusively.

A tutorial + example on getting started with WCF, *and* creating clean code can be found [here](http://code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0809101) and [here](https://github.com/derabbink/WcfTest).